# allow set_locale with strong_parameters gem & devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, strong-parameters

I'm using [strong parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) gem on small project with devise

I have added `User.rb` a `locale` column. This is my `controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb` file:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def resource_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :locale)
  end
  private :resource_params
  def create
   #add params[:locale] to resource.locale here
   super
  end
end
```

These are the parameters received from form:

```
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"ZyrtToHcwsX3zl2ive93cpYaom6HNGA/jnYcSg7pQUQ=", "user"=>{"username"=>"hyperrjas@hyperrjas.com", "email"=>"email@email.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Create account", "locale"=>"es"}
```

I would like add to `user :locale column` the parameter `params[:locale]`

**How can I do it?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem overriding the `create` method from this doc:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb.

If you want add specify `column or field locale` on your model user with `strong parameters gem`, you can add to `controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb` the next:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
    build_resource
    resource.locale = set_locale #set_locale or where you have stored your own locale
    if resource.save
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_navigational_format?
        expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end

  def resource_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :locale)
  end

  private :resource_params
end
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1

Handle it in the view.

Your view probably has something like:

```
<%= form_for :user do |f| %>
  <%= f.username %>
  <%= f.password %>
  <%= # Etc... %>
<% end >
<%= select_tag :locale, options_from_collection_for_select(I18n.config.available_locales, :to_s, :to_s), :selected => user.locale %>
```

So let's change this to:

```
<%= form_for :user do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select :locale, I18n.config.available_locales, :to_s, :to_s, :selected => user.locale %>
  <%= f.username %>
  <%= f.password %>
  <%= # Etc... %>
<% end >
```

That way, the params object will already nest `locale` in `user`.

### Option 2

Option 1's disadvantage is that your locale select might be in a navbar and it wouldn't make sense to move that into the form.  However, you can maintain 2 fields--the existing navbar one, and a hidden on in the form.

```
<%= form_for :user do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :locale, value => user.locale %>
  <%= f.username %>
  <%= f.password %>
  <%= # Etc... %>
<% end >
```

And use Javascript to copy the value from the navbar field to the hidden field before submitting:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(){
  $("#user_locale").val($("#locale").val());
});
```

### Option 3

Copy it over in the controller before setting your strong parameters:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  private
    def resource_params  
      params[:user][:locale] = params[:locale]
      params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :locale)
    end
end
```

All of these are much better alternatives to the accepted answer because they avoid code repetition.  You won't have to copy-and-paste again every time you want to upgrade devise.